# Blazor + Identity: why there is an error?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor

I'd like to use Blazor Server with ASP.NET Identity. But I need to use PostgreSQL as a User/Roles Store because it is in AWS.

It does not use EF, it is what I need.

1. I have created the new Blazor project.
2. Added the nuget package
   https://github.com/Robynhu/AspNetCore.Identity.PostgreSQL
3. I have modified the code as described in the package.
4. Build, run: click Register or Login:

   > Sorry, there's nothing at this address
5. I understand that something missed but what ? How to fix?

This is my project:
https://send.firefox.com/download/44d93569f4e7d732/#iVXL7tGMc5WVieFH6hb5jA

Answer (score 2):

I have added Scaffold item: Register,Login etc the Pages and some code were added to the project. It solved the problem.
Note: all default pages are in Identity Nuget package and if you want to replace Identity (as me) need to add Scaffold pages.